# Advertising in Friends

Tags: friends, product-placement

I am a big Friends fan and I've watched it many times.
Recently I kept noticing that Friends has a lot of product placement embedded into the show. For example:

- Be Your Own Windkeeper Book
- Porsche Cars
- Pottery Barn
- Macy's
- Bloomingdales
- Ralph Lauren
- Gucci
- Waxeen

I am not sure if Friends producers were paid to promote these brands or it was just for the purpose of the show.

There are few things that I thought it were advertising but were not, 
Gandalf the party guy for instance, I thought they were promoting for a party business but apparently it is just a fictional name.

Can anyone list the brands that appear in Friends?

Comment: It is common for TV shows to contain product placement, but I don't think, that there is a complete list of all products, which have been placed in Friends.

Comment: List questions are not encouraged here...especially as this one is **trivia** at best.

Comment: "Be Your Own Windkeeper" isn't a real book.

Comment: @BarryCarter Thats why I want to know what has been advertised, example : were they paid to mention "George Stephanopoulos"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a website that lists with pictures everytime a branded product is seen in friends, check it out [Here](https://productplacementblog.com/tag/friends/). **I have no affiliation with this site**. I would list them all out here but there are more than 90 which seems gratuitous for an answer.

Comment: The lists totally lacks beer brands which can be seen on the fridge in Joey&Chandler's apparment.

Comment: many thanks, it has many of the brands, yet there are still many other brands they talked about without having an image for